# What would be less taxing on an older system, a more old school system like debian or a lighter desktop environment like lxde?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, xfce, lxde

So I have 2008 Dell latitude e5400 laptop. It can be very slow and I am looking for a balanced OS to put on it. I have been using XFCE based ubuntu. I tried installing LXDE based debian on it today only to have it fail. I would like to try again but I had this idea in mind:

Would I have a more efficient system if I installed XFCE based Debian or LXDE based Ubuntu (like Lubuntu)? Would the core of the two distributions effect efficiency more or simply the two desktop environments?

I want to know because I have had much more experience using Ubuntu based distributions vs using Debian based distributions. I realize that ubuntu is a fork but I've never had an issue installing an ubuntu based distribution.

Yes I realize that these two are not mutually exclusive here.

Comment: I would go with something based on Ubuntu, since you're familiar with it. Try a minimal installation with a light desktop environment. If it's still too slow, you could look for another distribution that's targeted at older hardware. That may not be based on Ubuntu or Debian at all. It seems like something Ubuntu-based would work fine, if you can turn off enough services.